# confused by oracle error msg : PL/SQL: ORA-25137: Data value out of range

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

An error（PL/SQL: ORA-25137: Data value out of range ） was reported when I executed the following code in Oracle 21c.

```
create table t(id int ,j json);
insert into t values(1,'{"key":"valus"}');
```

```
DECLARE
  b varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  select cast(j as varchar2(100)) into b from t where id=1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(b);
END;
```

The error message is

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-25137: Data value out of range
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

The oracle version I used is

> Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 21.3.0.0.0

I can't understand why this error was reported.
I think the cast target size I set is enough, but "ORA-25137: Data value out of range" was reported.

Can anyone explain why？

Answer (score 3):

The data is stored in the table in binary format so you should use JSON_SERIALIZE function to convert JSON from any supported type into text. It is available since 19c:

```sql
Select t.id, json_serialize(t.j) From tbl t;

  id  j
----  -------------------
   1  {"key":"valus"}
```

or, for previous versions  use some of json functions like:

```sql
Select t.id, json_value(t.j, '$.key') as json_key From tbl t;

  id  json_key
----  -------------------
   1  valus
```

There are more functions and options to get your data using sql with json datatype (json_query(), json_table(), ...)
You can find more about it -- https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/json-data-type-21c

Comment: @d r that link doesn't work - could it be a paste error ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie Sorry, paste error. Should be ok now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm just trying to figure out why is this error thrown. If execute "select cast(j as varchar2(100)) from t where id=1;" in sql , it will success, but not plsql.

Comment: @KoenLostrie It is because instead of text that you are expecting you get something like "7B226672756974223A226170706C65222C227175616E74697479223A31307D" which are bytes